# Pin Window to Desktop

Tags: firefox, window-manager, window

How can I force one window to always remain at the back of the window stack? I want to run FireFox pinned to the desktop and prevent other windows from ever ending up behind it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does right-clicking on the window title and selecting "Keep below others" from the dropdown menu solves your problem? I do not have access to a Unity environment at the moment, but as I remember the option always was there.

**UPDATE:** Ok, after some checking I've found that the option is present in KDE, XFCE and LXDE (Kubuntu, Xubuntu and Lubuntu, respectively), but is disabled/hidden in Gnome, even in older versions.

Also, it seems that GTK [does have](http://developer.gnome.org/gdk/stable/gdk-Windows.html#gdk-window-set-keep-below) the required functionality, so it's just a matter of Gnome developers' preference not to expose "unnecessary" or rarely-used settings ("settings kill kittens", as they say). There may or may not be a hidden key somewhere which enables the menu item.

**UPDATE 2:** I was going to propose you to write a small program which finds a window using, say, [gtk_get_window_at_pointer](http://developer.gnome.org/gdk/stable/gdk-Windows.html#gdk-window-at-pointer) API call and sets it as "always on bottom" with [gdk_window_set_keep_below](http://developer.gnome.org/gdk/stable/gdk-Windows.html#gdk-window-set-keep-below) API call (in case you don't mind some programming), but it appears everything has been written for us already: there's a program called Devil's Pie (and also GDevilsPie) which are available in Ubuntu repositories. The program allows you to write some rules which match open windows and perform some actions on them (move to a specific workspace, maximize, minimize etc.)

Here's the [documentation](http://www.foosel.org/linux/devilspie)

Here's [an aricle](http://www.alfredrossi.com/?p=5) discussing specifically how to implement "below others" functionality using Devil's Pie or another program called `wmctrl`

To prevent link rot:

> As an example, the first snippet below will toggle the full screen
>   state of whichever window is selected with the mouse. The second
>   example does almost exactly what we want, it toggles the always on
>   bottom state of the active window.
>
> ```
> wmctrl -r :SELECT: -b toggle,fullscreen
>
> wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -b toggle,below
> ```

Comment: There's only "Always on top".

Comment: That's great thanks very much. Is there a way launch firefox via the command line so that it always uses the "Keep Below Others" Setting?

Comment: I've updated my answer

Comment: @Sergey: Thanks to you, I have this working with XFCE and Devis's Pie. Thanks for the detail you've given in answering my question. It's *hugely* appreciated. It didn't occur to me to try and use wmctrl for this. I'll try this next.

Comment: @Sparky1 How did you achieve the result when launching your application from the command line?

Answer (score 0):

*Install CompizConfig Settings Manager if you haven't already*

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

*Run it by searching for ccsm in Dash*

Go to the **Window Rules** plugin in Compiz. Under the **Matches** tab, add ***class=Firefox*** to the **Below** entry.

[image]

Comment: This only applies if the OP is using the Compiz window manager.

Comment: Agreed. OP didn't state what desktop (s)he's running.